# The efficient way to make external data structure updater UI

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I have a class contains a lot of properties. One of them needs a special UI to be edited. 
The user may press edit to this property in the UI then he make changes and either press OK or Cancel

e.g.

```
class A{
    private List<Employee> employees;

    public void EditMyEmployees(){
        EmployeeEditorForm editor = new EmployeeEditor(employees);
        if(editor.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK){
           employees = editor.GetEditedEmployeesList();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem in the previous code that the editor has a copy of the reference to the employees List

and when the editor makes any edits in the List it will be reflected in the original object.
So, pressing OK or Cancel will have the same effect (the object is already updated) and no need for the step

```
employees = editor.GetEditedEmployeesList();
```

I know that making deep copy for the employees array before sending it to the editor will solve the problem but still I think this is not the efficient way to do it

I am looking for a design pattern that can make this in a better way.

Comment: You could use the command pattern.  Your editor wouldn't directly update the employees list, it would create commands that could be applied to modify the list.  If the user hit OK, the commands would be applied, if not they would be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to deep copy the whole collection. You just need to keep track of the elements that changed. Within your `EmployeeEditor`, use three lists (`List<Employee>` to keep track of:

1. Added employees
2. Removed employees
3. Changed employees

Upon Cancel, you would need to remove the "added" items, add back the "removed" items, and replace the changed items with their original state.

Note that the changed employees list would need to keep a copy of the original state of the object. If the `Employee` class has some sort of unique id, you can match cased on that id. Otherwise, the "changed" list would need to be a `List<Tuple<Employee, Employee>>` so that you can store the matching items.

Also note that, when changes happen in the employees list, you also need to make necessary changes in those three lists. For example, if an new employee is added and then removed, you also need to remove that record from the "added" list. Or it is possible an employee is changed and then removed, in which case you also need to remove from "changed" list.

Having said all this, if I were you, I would make a decision based on the expected use cases and *real* performance problems (not anticipated performance issues).  It is very likely that simply deep copying your collection is the simplest and least error prone way.

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of changes involved here: (1) changes to the list (Add / Remove) and (2) changes to individual elements of the list (employees in this case).

Now, part of the problem comes from the semantics of OK/Cancel. If you restrict the scope of these two buttons to changes of the second kind (i.e., changes to the elements of the list), you will be able to handle Remove with a confirmation dialog on this particular action ("Remove such and such"?). For the Addition you don't need anything special, just add a new element to the list. If the user changes their mind they will still have the Remove action available.

For changes on a particular element (second kind) you can use the command pattern as mentioned in the comment. More simply, you could initialize temporary variables for all the fields your editor displays from the element under edition. As the user modifies some values your editor will update the corresponding temporaries. If the user press Cancel you will simply forget those changes (or reinitialize them from the element). If the user press Apply (yes, you should include the Apply button also,) you will now write each of the temporary values onto the corresponding element's attribute. If the user hits OK you would Apply and Close.